# How do I inform a React component of the width of the space it is supposed to render in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Menu` React component that renders differently depending on the with of the div that it is supposed to render inside.  I have tried many different ways of using `document.getElementById()` to select the div the menu is inside so that I can then use `.offsetWidth` property to get the width of that div. but no matter where in my code I put the `document.getElementById()` call it is returning `null`
so I get a `TypeError: cannot read property offsetWidth of null`.

Specifically, I currently have this code which I expected to let me use props.availableWidth inside the definition of the Menu component but it won't compile due to the above-mentioned error.

```
<div id="menu-section">
   <Menu availableWidth={document.getElementById("menu-section").offsetWidth} />
</div>
```

Is there a different method I should be using besides getElementById() or is that the right method and I'm using it in the wrong place?

Comment: You have no way on knowing the rendered element's width before rendering (which is when props are evaluated). Basically you're telling react to get the width of a component that doesn't exist in the dom yet. The way you do it is you mount everything as is and after that you calculate the width (using componentDidMount for example) and pass it as prop, so your Menu component will rerender with adequate width. With that said... can't you accomplish similar results using css?

Comment: @Nigel, can you please mark one of the answers as accepted if it worked for you?

Comment: @GiorgioZanni I was thinking there might be a way to use CSS but I want to conditionally render one react component or another.  I am familiar with using CSS @ rules to show/hide elements by setting `display: none` and `display: flex` and switching which element has which display setting using CSS references to the `viewport width` but is there a way that I can (1) use the width of the containing di rather than the whole screen? and (2) conditionally render React components in CSS, not just use display property as I described above?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ResizeObserver` API to observe the width of the component. Here's a working example I created. Hope it helps :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-filepond-live-demo-7v3v9?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Is `ResizeObserver` a lifecycle method like `ComponentDidMount` ?  most other answers directed me toward  `ComponentDidMount`  but I want it to be responsive as a browser window resizes, not just to make the determination once on the initial rendering.

Comment: No ResizeObserver is a Javascript API that listens to the changes to size of a DOM node . Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

Answer (score 0):

Well, I understood that you are using **getElementById** to adjust the width available in div for Menu component, right?

So, you can use CSS setting `width: 100%` to Menu component. This will make the Menu component use all the width available in div, but if you wants to control how much width the Menu component will use from div, you could develop a logic to change the width conditionally.

Obs: The error is throwing because is calling the `getElementById` before mounts the HTML with the id that you are searching.